# Replacing where not by find_each in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following query

```
Task.where.not(client_ids: nil, client_ids: []).all
```

Because of loading issues, I need to replace this by `find_each`. How can I insert a negation operator into the `find_each` in Rails?

Comment: Thanksf for the catch. Slipped the find_each to foreach by mistake :D

Comment: Is the question clear now or needs editing from your point of view?

Comment: Yes. However `.find_each` is a method that you call on a scope so there is no need to replace anything except `all`. `Task.where.not(client_ids: nil).find_each {|record| ... }`.

Comment: OKKKK. This is embarassing. Thanks!

Comment: You're also passing duplicate hash keys. Ruby won't warn you but the later one will just override it.

Comment: Is there a way to do it with a single hash key? Tried where.not(client_ids: [nil, []]) but didnt work

Comment: What is it actually supposed to accomplish? `client_ids` implies that there is some kind of table that you should be joining.

Comment: If you for example want to get Tasks with a client you just do an inner join - `Task.joins(:clients)...`.

Comment: Its not, its a json field.

But thankfully found a solution .not(client_ids: [nil, {}])

Thanks for the suggestion and the solution!!!

Comment: Thats worse in every possible way... but whatever floats your boat for the next hour.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using rails 7, maybe you want to use the newish missing:

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/WhereChain.html#method-i-missing

Task.where.missing(:clients).find_each

Though it's hard to tell from the code you shared exactly what your models look like.